# MS Word. How to copy exact strings to another document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to copy a word always begining with exact string "p1" and copy that word to a table in another document. Then copy a sentence always between exact strings and copy that sentence to the same table.

let me explain with an example. Here are few paragraphs of text I need to copy from:

```
variable labels p1consid 'SDQ: Considerate (Parent1)'.

variable labels p1restles 'SDQ: Restless (Parent1)'.

variable labels p1somatic 'SDQ: Headache, stomach-ache (Parent1)'.
```

So, "p1consid" should go to a column 1 of a table, and "SDQ: Considerate (Parent1)" to a column 2 of the same table.

COLUMN 1

```
p1consid

p1restles

p1somatic
```

COLUMN 2

```
SDQ: Considerate (Parent1)

SDQ: Restless (Parent1)

SDQ: Headache, stomach-ache (Parent1)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of assumptions in this code but try this for a start.

It assumes the source documents formatting is as you described and that a 2-column table exists in the destination document. The table is the first table, there are no header rows and it is a single row table.

```
Sub CopyStrings()
Dim docSrc As word.Document, docDst As word.Document
Dim rng As word.Range, tbl As word.Table, tRng As word.Range
Set docSrc = Documents.Open("Your Source Doc")
Set docDst = Documents.Open("Your Destination Doc")
Set rng = docSrc.Content
Set tbl = docDst.Content.Tables(1)
With rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Text = "p1"
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
    Do While .found
        rng.MoveEnd word.WdUnits.wdWord, Count:=1
        Set tRng = tbl.rows(1).Cells(1).Range
        tRng.MoveEnd word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        tRng.Collapse word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        tRng.Text = rng.Text & vbCr
        rng.Collapse word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        rng.MoveStart word.WdUnits.wdWord, Count:=1
        rng.MoveStart word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=1
        rng.MoveEnd word.WdUnits.wdParagraph, Count:=1
        Set tRng = tbl.rows(1).Cells(2).Range
        tRng.MoveEnd word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        tRng.Collapse word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        tRng.Text = rng.Text
        rng.Collapse word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        .Execute
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @DanielHamilton You are welcome and you can thank me me by voting it up and marking it as the answer.

Comment: oh ok :) thanks for that also, didn't know how to mark as an answer (a bit hard to notice). i also upvoted but since my reputation is less than 15 it is not publicly noticeable. thanks again, you're so kind.